Snowflake stored procedure creation IMPORTS param gets modified
I am using Snowflake and during a deployment procedure I am cloning my existing production database and running migrations on the cloned database. When I create a procedure through the migration script which uses an external stage Snowflake registers my procedure to my cloned database.
My migrations script ran on the CLONED database:
use schema mirror;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE 
DATA_STAGE.CREATE_STRUCTURE_DDL_FILES(P_SCHEMA_NAME VARCHAR)
COPY GRANTS
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE PYTHON
RUNTIME_VERSION = '3.8'
PACKAGES = ('snowflake-snowpark-python')
HANDLER = 'SF_CREATE_DDL_FILES.create_object_ddl_files'
IMPORTS = ('@DATA_STAGE.PYTHON_SCRIPTS/SF_CREATE_DDL_FILES.py')
EXECUTE AS CALLER
;

The result when I check it in the database view:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MY_CLONED_DATABASE.DATA_STAGE.CREATE_STRUCTURE_DDL_FILES("P_SCHEMA_NAME" VARCHAR(16777216))
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE PYTHON
RUNTIME_VERSION = '3.8'
PACKAGES = ('snowflake-snowpark-python')
HANDLER = 'SF_CREATE_DDL_FILES.create_object_ddl_files'
IMPORTS = ('@MY_CLONED_DATABASE.DATA_STAGE.PYTHON_SCRIPTS/SF_CREATE_DDL_FILES.py')
EXECUTE AS CALLER
;

As you can see it has added the MY_CLONED_DATABASE prefix to the creation and imports parts.
When the deployment renames the cloned database to the original name MY_DATABASE this IMPORTS parameter will cause an error, since the database referenced will be deleted.
How can I avoid this?

it gets registered under the context that the command was run so you need to change your context to the DB/schema you want the stored procedure to be in.    If you want the stored procedure to be in the cloned DB after you rename it, then that is a Snowflake support question as it should rename the context for the SP as well.

@Sorceri thanks, this is exactly what happens here. After the rename (from cloned to original db name) the context is not updated. So I have a procedure in my new database that is referencing my non-existing cloned database. Already sent them a support request and will update the question if there's any reply.
